# How can I get a subcovariance from a covariance matrix in python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, covariance, covariance-matrix

I have a covariance matrix (as a pandas DataFrame) in python as follows:

```
    a   b   c    
a   1   2   3    
b   2   10  4    
c   3   4   100
```

And I want dynamically to select only a subset of the covariance of matrix. For example a subset of A and C would look like

```
    a   c
a   1   3    
c   3   100
```

Is there any function that can select this subset?

Thank you!

Comment: Is it a numpy matrix?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your covariance matrix is a numpy array like this:

```
cov = np.array([[1, 2,  3],
                [2, 10, 4],
                [3, 4, 100]])
```

Then you can get the desired submatrix by [advanced indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#purely-integer-array-indexing):

```
subset = [0, 2]  # a, c

cov[np.ix_(subset, subset)]

# array([[  1,   3],
#        [  3, 100]])
```

**Edit**:

If your covariance matrix is pandas DataFrame (e.g. obtained as `cov = df.cov()` for some dataframe `df` with columns `'a', 'b', 'c', ...`), to get the subset of `'a'` and `'c'` you can do the following:

```
cov.loc[['a','c'], ['a','c']]
```

Comment: Works like a charm for numpy arrays but I have a data frame.